# How can I run Win10 Camera application via command?

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

This is the Win10 built-in Camera application.
[image]

We usually can run a normal Windows applicaion via command like

```
notepad
calc
```

in cmd or powerShell.

For the camera APP, I inspected the process via spy++
[image]

The process is ApplicationFrameHost.exe and with -Embedding parameter.
However, I run this command in PowerShell and turned out not work.

```
ApplicationFrameHost -Embedding
```

[image]

How do I run the Win10 camera APP via command line? Or I use C++, which function can achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Type follwing command in cmd.

```
start microsoft.windows.camera:
```

Comment: What does the trailing colon mean? (I checked, and it is indeed mandatory).